# Why Firefox doesn't get a <form> $_GET variable while Safari does it?

Tags: javascript, php, html, firefox

I am sending the content of a an input through a form, from page1 to page2, using a button with `action="page2.php"`:

```
<form method="get" id="chatform" action="page2.php">
    <input type="text" style="margin-bottom:20px;" class="form-control" id="recipient" name="recipient" placeholder="username" value="">
</form>
```

the button is outside the form but it contains the name of it:

```
<button type="submit" form="chatform" id="b9" style="font-size: 12px !important;" name="b9" class="buttonmenu toggleForms btn btn-secondary btn-block" style="float:left;">Chat</button>
```

ALSO I am loadind the input with javascript:

```
$(".buttonmenu").click(function(){
$('#recipient').val("hellooooo"); }
```

the problem is that everything works fine for Safari but in Firefox I don't get anything in the variable `$_GET['recipient']` and I don't understand why.

In page1 there are just forms in series, no nested froms. In Safari everything is working perfectly in page2: I get the name of the 'recipient' variable in the URL and the content, in firefox I get just the name of the 'recipient' variable in the URL but the variable is empty
It seems like Firefox can't get the CONTENT of `$_GET['recipient']` from the server, or run the php action IGNORING the javascript.

Any idea?

Comment: `action="chat.php"` vs `action="page2.php"` ... so ... and there's no submit button

Comment: Apologies, it is action="page2.php"- just correct it in the question

Comment: how are you sending your form to that page?

Comment: Confusing Question. Please Details

Comment: the button is out of the form but it contains the name of the form: <button type="submit" form="chatform" id="b9" style="font-size: 12px !important;" name="b9" class="buttonmenu  toggleForms btn btn-secondary btn-block" style="float:left;">Chat</button>

Comment: When you submit the form, does the parameter appear in the url? Best guess is that you are submitting the wrong form/having multiple nested forms, having multiple input's with the same `id` or some other html undefined behavior. But without more context that is impossible to know for sure.

Comment: in Safari everything is working perfectly: I get the name of the 'recipient' variable  in the URL and the content, in firefox I get just the name of the 'recipient' variable  in the URL but appear empty

Comment: you should put the button inside the form. but you can position it somwhere else

Comment: @giuseppe That is why I think that. Browsers act differently on undefined behavior. Try use something like [this](https://validator.w3.org) on your **whole** page to see if you have any errors. Fix those and then check if you still have the same problem.

Comment: In page1 there are just forms in series, no nested froms. As I said, in Safari everything is working perfectly in page2: I get the name of the 'recipient' variable in the URL and the content, in firefox I get just the name of the 'recipient' variable in the URL but the variable is empty

Answer (score 0):

**1)** make sure that your form is not (nested) inside another form element like so: 
*(also make sure its not inside `<tr>`, `<td>`, or `<table>` elements)*

```
<form>
    ...

    <form>
        ...
    </form>

    ...
</form>
```

**2)** Make sure your code works, the code below works so try this and see if it makes a difference

**page1.php:**

```html
<form action="page2.php" method="GET" id="chatform">
  <input type="text" style="margin-bottom:20px;" class="form-control" id="recipient" name="recipient" placeholder="username" value="">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

**page2.php:**

```
$recipient = $_GET['recipient'];
echo $recipient;
```

**3)** Try clearing cache and cookies. Sometimes forms can break accordinf to this question asked on the firefox helpc centre:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1144267

This article states...

> Many site issues can be caused by corrupt cookies or cache.
>
> - Clear the Cache
> - and Remove Cookies
>
>   Warning ! ! This will log you out of sites you're logged in to.
>     Type about:preferences in the address bar.
> - Cookies; Select Privacy. Under History, select Firefox will Use Custom
>     Settings. Press the button on the right side called Show Cookies. Use
>     the search bar to look for the site. Note; There may be more than one
>     entry. Remove All of them.
> - Cache; Select Advanced > Network. Across
>     from Cached Web Content, Press Clear Now. If there is still a problem,
>     Start Firefox in Safe Mode {web link} A small dialog should appear.
>     Click Start In Safe Mode (not Refresh). While you are in safe mode;
>
> Type about:preferences#advanced in the address bar.
>
> Under Advanced, Select General. Look for and turn off Use Hardware
>   Acceleration.

**4)** make sure that the file to the file is 100% correct! make sure it really is `page2.php` and also try the action with a slash at the start like so: `"/page2.php"`

Comment: WHen I run your code snippet in Firefox I get : Server Error
404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable

Comment: is your file actually called page2.php or was this just an example?

Comment: okay well definitely make sure the file name is correct (reread my answer as I have added a few more things like point 4 and point 1)

Comment: Fine Ryan, thank you. I did all the steps but Firefox is still the problem. I have updated my question with more details, the code is working perfectly on Safari, but with firefox doesn't. Thanks

Comment: I think you are too wrapped up in the idea that firefox is the problem. regardless of whether it works in safari or not your code is probably still incorrect and safari just has better protocols in place to correct peoples bad code. For debugging purposes try putting the submit button the form and see what happens. Also im interested to know how you know that the form isn't working. Do you have the result echoing out like I suggested?

Comment: Yes Ryan, I did echoing it.  Also, when you run that code you can see from the URL if the "action", the name of input variable and content are sent to the page2. Comparing these you can say that Safari is getting the content of the variable but Firfox doesn't.

Comment: did you try putting the submit button in the form just to check?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

Firefox needs the 'event' object as function's param.

This is the line:

```
$(".buttomenu").click(function(event) {.....
```